# Linq take 3 records from each category

Tags: c#, linq

I have column "Category" in my table and I want to take 3 rows from each category.
here example of my table:

```
 ID | Category | Text
----------------------
 01 |    TST   | Text here
 02 |    TST   | Text2 here
 03 |    TST   | Text3 here
 04 |    TST   | Text4 here
 01 |   TST02  | Text here
 02 |   TST02  | Text2 here
 03 |   TST02  | Text3 here
 04 |   TST02  | Text4 here
 05 |   TST02  | Text5 here
```

And this is why I want to get back:

```
 ID | Category | Text
----------------------
 01 |    TST   | Text here
 02 |    TST   | Text2 here
 03 |    TST   | Text3 here
 01 |   TST02  | Text here
 02 |   TST02  | Text2 here
 03 |   TST02  | Text3 here
```

How I can done it with LINQ?

I tried to do like this:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.Category).Take(3)
```

But after that I cant use .Select

**Update:**
When I using SelectMany I'm getting an error:

> Query Source could not be identified: ItemName = x, ItemType = System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,ADDE.Models.Notification], Expression = from IGrouping`2 x in {from Notification w in value(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[ADDE.Models.Notification]) where ([w].UserId == 04bccede-46d0-44f8-814b-346d5510acb8) orderby [w].Time asc select [w] => GroupBy([w].Category, [w])}

**Update 2:**
Here is my code:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.Category).SelectMany(x => x.Take(3)).Select(
                                                     s =>
                                                     new NotificationData
                                                         {
                                                             Category = s.Category,
                                                             Text = s.Text,
                                                             Time = DateTime.Now.Subtract(s.Time)
                                                         })
```

Comment: I'd point you out to a **[GroupBy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35667/How-to-Use-LINQ-GroupBy)** method. You can group your data by category and take 3 from each group.

Comment: [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is useful to visualize the elements resulting from operators like `.GroupBy`. It's `.Dump()` extension method would show you the structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use this:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Category)
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Take(3));
```

Comment: @Clint: Yeah, that's important to flatten the result.

Comment: @RafaelZilberman:  Please give me the exact error message along with the name of the exception.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth 3.3.2.4000

Comment: Did anyone find solution.. I am facing a similar problem